# исключающие запросы mysql

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица с несколькими полями, ключевые поля для задачи:
card_id
payment_date

Есть несколько строк с одинаковым card_id и разными значениями payment_date
Мне нужно выбрать только те card_id у которых ни в одной строке нет payment_date=NUll. 
Если хоть в одной строке с card_id есть значение payment_date = NULL такие значения не выводить. 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/535867/1 это ссылка готовой таблицы для экспериментов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужны записи, то так:

```
SELECT
 *
FROM
  orders
where card_id not in (select card_id from orders where payment_date is null)
```

Если только card_id, то так:

```
select card_id from orders
group by card_id 
having sum(if(payment_date is null,1,0))=0;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fbdba/4

Comment: первый работает..

Comment: второй тоже работает..спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно выбрать просто все записи у которых payment_date не равно NULL, то:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE payment_date IS NOT NULL;
```

Если требуется выбрать именно при наборе одинаковых (c группировкой по card_id) у которых нет пустого payment_date, то

```
  SELECT card_id, payment_date FROM orders GROUP BY card_id HAVING COUNT(IF (payment_date IS NOT NULL, NULL, 1))=0;
```

**HAVING** позволяет наложить условие на группу.

Comment: Не сработало.. все равно выдало одну строку из двух.. даже с HAVING

Comment: @Durrasell извините, ошибся :) Попробуйте измененный запрос с COUNT из моего ответа.

Comment: сейчас попробую

Comment: Работает спасибо